# can I add a parameter to my promise callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, promise

I have a promise call back that needs some external data.  how can I do that?  myDataINeed in this code is always null.

```
var myDataVariable = "some dynamic data set above"; 
var promActions = [];
 for(var k in loop){
   promActions.push(externalCall(loop[k]));
 }
 var promResults = Promise.all(promActions);
 let myDataINeed = myDataVariable;
 promResults.then(function(responseArray, myDataINeed){
    ....do stuff with responseArray and myDataINeed
 });
```

edit: 
I added a value to myDataVariable so you can see it is set to something.  myDataINeed is not in scope inside the .then function.  How do I get at it during the promise.then?

Comment: [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: `.then` callbacks receive exactly one argument, you can't just add an argument and expect the promise to "know what you need" - besides, the code you've shown, `myDataINeed` is accessible inside that `.then` because it's still in scope (as long as you don't "mask" it with an argument like you have in your code) i.e. remove the argument from the .then callback, and presto chango, `myDataINeed` will be the data you need : p.s. in this code, `myDataINeed` would be `undefined` not `null` (inside the .then callback anyway)

Comment: _"myDataINeed in this code is always null"_ What is `myDataVariable`?

Comment: Your original definition of `myDataINeed` is already in scope in your `.then()` handler.  You don't need to pass it to the `.then()` handler (and, in fact, can't make another parameter for the `.then()` handler).  Instead, you can just access the definition you already have directly (if you remove it from the `.then()` handler argument list).

Comment: @jfriend00 _"(and, in fact, can't make another parameter for the `.then()` handler)"_?

Comment: @guest271314 - I don't know what your comment to me means, but all `.then()` handlers get exactly one argument.  If you make that one argument an object, you can put as many properties on it as you want, but you only get ONE argument.  That's how the promise spec is defined. You can't have two or more arguments to a `.then()` handler function.

Comment: @jfriend00 `.bind()` can be used with a named function `function fn(data, responseArray) {
  console.log(a, b)
}.then(fn.bind(null, myDataINeed))`.

Comment: @guest271314 - That's wrapping it in another function as a work-around.  Yes, you can do that if you want of you can even define your own wrapper function that then passes some other function as many arguments as you want.  The actual `.then()` handler still gets one argument.  In this case, `myDataINeed` is already in scope of the `.then()` handler and if the offending 2nd argument is removed, the existing variable can be used directly with no use of `.bind()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Could be incorrect, though appears `myDataINeed` is an asynchronous function call. OP could chain that call to `promResults`, return an array, then use `.then()` at Question

Comment: @guest271314 - Who knows?  It's a bad, unclear question.  As declared, the variable is in scope and available.

Comment: @guest271314 `appears myDataINeed is an asynchronous function call` doesn't appear like a function call at all

Comment: @JaromandaX Not sure what issue is then?

Comment: I think the issue is that declaring the parameter as the same name as the var required masks the var required

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Since OP has not responded here at all and has not clarified the question in any way - I'm voting to close as "Unclear What They Are Asking".  We're just wasting time talking to ourselves when the OP isn't responsive to people trying to help them.  Not worth spending time talking to a brick wall - IMO.  People who post here have to learn to check back several times in the first 30 and 60 minutes of posting to make sure their question is clear and understood.

Comment: wow this got a good discussion going.  I am looking into the bind option.  The problem is that myDataINeed is null because it is out of scope by the time the .then of the promise is run.  I don't want to pass myDataINeed into the promise call only to bundle it up in the response for use inside the .then scope

Comment: @spartikus You don't seem to understand how scope works. A variable can't "go out of scope" of a nested function. If it's in that function's scope at some point, then it will always be in that scope. The problem is that you are shadowing it with a new variable that does nothing.

Comment: @JLRishe - thanks for the response.  I am seeing a myDataINeed is undefined inside the .then regardless of if I pass it in or not.  So basically I was thinking this was out of scope at the time of the .then running

Comment: @spartikus Have you checked whether it actually has a value before you call `.then()`?

Comment: yes it is set prior to the promise executing

Comment: Please provide a (simplified) snippet that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the data available in the scope where you're calling `then`, then you don't need to do anything special to access it inside the `then`. It will be available through the magic of closures.

In the attempt in your question, you are actually *shadowing* the `myDataINeed` variable by declaring it as a parameter in the `then` callback, so that value will always be undefined.

To get it to work, all you need to do is remove that parameter:

```
var myDataVariable = "some dynamic data set above"; 
var promActions = [];
for(var k in loop){
   promActions.push(externalCall(loop[k]));
}
var promResults = Promise.all(promActions);
let myDataINeed = myDataVariable;
promResults.then(function(responseArray){  // <-- remove the myDataINeed parameter
    ....do stuff with responseArray and myDataINeed
});
```

On a separate note, and not specifically pertaining to promises, if `loop` is an array (and I presume it is), then there is a problem with using that loop. You should not use `for .. in` with arrays. If it is indeed an array, you can accomplish what you are trying to do more reliably *and* concisely using `.map`:

```
var myDataVariable = "some dynamic data set above"; 
var promActions = loop.map(externalCall);
var promResults = Promise.all(promActions);
let myDataINeed = myDataVariable;
promResults.then(function(responseArray){  // <-- remove the myDataINeed parameter
    ....do stuff with responseArray and myDataINeed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> myDataINeed in this code is always null;

A promise `all` resolves to a single array value. So `promResults.then(function(responseArray, myDataINeed){` is wrong. `promResults.then(function(responseArray){`is right.

## More

`myDataINeed` will need to come from some external source i.e. not from `Promise.all`.